# Hatcher's problem $0.5$ about nullhomotopy

Tags: general-topology

> Show that if a space $X$ deformation retracts to a point $x \in X$, then for each neighborhood $U$ of $x$ in $X$ there exists a neighborhood $V \subset U$ of $x$ such that the inclusion map $V\hookrightarrow U$ is nullhomotopic.

I've seen a post here using something called the tube lemma, but I don't quite understand why would we need something like that?

If $X$ deformation retracts to a point say $x_0$, then doesn't it imply that $X$ is contractible which in turn would make the identity $id_X$ nullhomotopic to the constant map $c_{x_0}$. Now if $id_X \simeq c_{x_0}$, then restricting the identity to $V$ we get the inclusion $V \hookrightarrow U$ so I suspect that this should also be nullhomotopic as $id_X$ being nullhomotopic is a stronger argument?

Answer (score 0):

The point is that you want to be nullhomotopic **in $U$**.

Consider $X=\Bbb R^2$, $x=1$, $U=\Bbb S^1_\varepsilon = \{ y \mid \vert \Vert y \Vert - 1\vert < \varepsilon \}$.

For $V=U$ the identity map is **not** nullhomotopic, since $\Bbb S^1_\varepsilon \simeq \Bbb S^1$ is **not** contractible.

But of cause $V=\Bbb B_\varepsilon(x)$ provides a contractible neighborhood of $x$ in $U$.